# Using Matlab function `trisurf` to display results

Tags: debugging, matlab, plot, numerical-methods

I've obtained a solution, `u` from Gauss-Siedel (solving 2D Poisson's equation), and I want to plot it using `trisurf`. I can't, however, seem to understand how `trisurf` works (I have tried playing around with it, but with no luck). I've also taken a look at the Matlab documentation, but I don't understand what peaks is. Currently, I have something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
ss = a:h:b; %subspace
[X,Y] = meshgrid(ss,ss);
tri = delaunay(X,Y);
Z = peaks(ss);
trisurf(tri,X,Y,Z);
```

Where I plug in the solution values (the vector `u`)? And what types of values does `peaks` have to take in this context?

Details:

- `a` = lower bound
- `b` = upper bound
- `h` = step size
- `u` = solution
  from Gauss-Siedel. Its size depends on the number of points I
  evaluate on the mesh. The solution should converge as I It's obtained from running `i` many iterations.

Comment: Can you please include the numbers that you are using?

Comment: Or at least the size of your matrices from `whos`?

Comment: @JesseB What matrix are you speaking about? `u` is a vector

Comment: In place of matrix, I mean vector in my earlier comment. I don’t see how you’re using `u` in your code.

Comment: @JesseB Exactly, I don't know how to. I've never used trimesh before.

Comment: If I could see what you have instead of something like what you have, maybe I could be more helpful. That’s what I mean to say.

Comment: @JesseB I'm trying to plot the results from Gauss-Siedel. I'm testing to see if it is working properly. If I increase the iterations, then the solution should increase, which I would be able to tell by looking at a plot.

Comment: I think I understand your problem now. Check to see if my answer helped ya.

Answer (score 1):

First off, let me give you my output from `whos`

```
  triangle_obj       1x1               540  TriScatteredInterp              
  u                 15x1               120  double                          
  X                 15x1               120  double                          
  Y                 15x1               120  double
```

Try the approach below. I think you might find that this works for you (assuming that none of your points are collinear). You might have been confused because of the [X, Y] argument confusion in TriScatteredInterp.

```
triangle_obj = TriScatteredInterp([X, Y], u);
figure
trisurf(triangle_obj, X, Y, u);
```

Comment: (revised to use trisurf instead of trimesh; my mistake)